# breaking out of an "if" statement and going back to the start of a "for" loop

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, break

So, for an assignment for class, I have to take user input and assign the amount of "food" that my gerbil objects can use per day. In this situation, I have already taken the max amount of food daily from the user and need to give an error message to the user if they attempt to input a value above the daily max.

If this is the case, they need to be re-prompted to enter the amount of food the gerbil eats.

I can't seem to figure out how to break out of the "if" statement and go back to the top of the "for" loop. Here is my code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFoods; j++) {
    System.out.println(gerbilId[index].substring(index)
            + " eats how many " + foodNames[j] + "s per day");
    int amountOfFood = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (amountOfFood > foodMax[j]) {
        System.out.println("Error. Please input a valid amount of food");
        break;
    } else {
        gerbilConsumption[index] = amountOfFood;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into `continue`.

Comment: Sorry, but there's nothing to down vote this post. People often mix up questions which show lack of effort with the ones which show effort but may not know something which is the reason why the question  was asked in the first place.

Comment: Why do you want to "break out of your if statement" you are making things more confusing for yourself.

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: Yeah, this is my first comp sci class so I'm pretty new to everything. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Just looking at your code and one thing is a bit strange - you are looping through `numberOfFoods` for each gerbil - but there is only a single consumption value stored - so the consumption for food 0 will be overwritten by the consumption of food 1 which will be overwritten by food 2 and so on...  Should it perhaps be `gerbilConsumption[index] = gerbilConsumption[index] + amountOfFood;` to keep a total of all food consumption per gerbil?

Comment: This is true. I actually need to keep seperate food consumption for each individual food, not just the total amount of consumption. Back to work I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers saying use `continue` are wrong as they are not what you're looking for in this situation. `continue` will move you on to the next food type, but if the input was invalid you want to stay on the same one. You need to do `j--;` to make that number be used again

```
if (amountOfFood > foodMax[j]) {
    System.out.println("Error. Please input a valid amount of food");
    j--;
} else {
    gerbilConsumption[index] = amountOfFood;
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you downvoted my answer.  I've updated it, please look at my reasoning and consider removing your downvote.

Comment: No it wasn't me at all, I'm sorry to see that you got downvoted for writing something that is still helpful even if not what he's looking for in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restart the for loop then do this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFoods; j++) {
    System.out.println(gerbilId[index].substring(index)
            + " eats how many " + foodNames[j] + "s per day");
    int amountOfFood = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (amountOfFood > foodMax[j]) {
        System.out.println("Error. Please input a valid amount of food");
        j = -1;  //instead of break
    } else {
        gerbilConsumption[index] = amountOfFood;
    }
}
```

The variable `j` will become `0` in the next iteration and the loop restarts.

On the other hand, if you only want to continue the `for` loop then use `continue` in place of `break`. But this is pointless in this case as that will happen automatically.

As it's unclear what is needed here, if you want to stay in the same iteration level, I'd advise you use a `while` loop inside.

```
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFoods; j++) {
    System.out.println(gerbilId[index].substring(index)
            + " eats how many " + foodNames[j] + "s per day");
    int amountOfFood = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (amountOfFood > foodMax[j]) {
        System.out.println("Error. Please input a valid amount of food");
        amountOfFood = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    gerbilConsumption[index] = amountOfFood;
}
```

Comment: You're right but I think he needs `j--;` not `j = -1;` because you want to do the same iteration of the loop again, not start the entire for loop again

Comment: @jimmycarr it's quiet unclear what the OP wants but +1 to your response.

Comment: @carloscollazo It works perfectly until you enter an amount above the maximum when you are on the 2nd or 3rd numberOfFoods loop and it jumps you back to 0 unexpectedly.

Comment: @CodeCamper I think that's what the OP wants. The reason, I don't know.

Comment: As some have said the j-- actually works better for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @carloscollazo Then, you only need the last part of my answer. Next time, try and make your question clearer. It helps the community.

Comment: @carloscollazo you don't have to go through the entire for loop again and will be harmful if you add more code there. If you look at my answer you can use a while and break out of it when you get the response you want which is a much better way of doing it, why repeat the whole for loop? In case you decide to add other things there.

Answer (score 0):

> give an error message to the user if they attempt to input a value
>   above the daily max.
>
> If this is the case, they need to be re-prompted to enter the amount
>   of food the gerbil eats.

You can't skip out of your for loop because you are adding to J which will confuse you.

Use code like this if you need to accomplish the above(insert it into your for loop)

```
while(true){
//prompt amount of gerbil food
//if input equal or below daily max then BREAK;
//tell user they are above daily max
}
```

Or using your code from your post...

```
int amountOfFood;
while(true){
 amountOfFood=keyboard.nextInt();
 if (amountOfFood <= foodMax[j]) break;
 System.out.println("Error. Please input a valid amount of food");
}
 gerbilConsumption[index] = amountOfFood;
```

As you can see I inverted your check. It is better for you to check what IS valid, rather than check what IS NOT valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could also re-structure to use a `do...while` loop -

```
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfFoods; j++) {
    System.out.println(gerbilId[index].substring(index)
            + " eats how many " + foodNames[j] + "s per day");
    int amountOfFood=-1;

    do 
    {
       amountOfFood = keyboard.nextInt();
       if (amountOfFood > foodMax[j] || amountOfFood <0) {
        System.out.println("Error. Please input a valid amount of food");
        amountOfFood=-1;
       }
    } while (amountOfFood == -1);

    gerbilConsumption[index] = amountOfFood; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Technically**, you are looking for the Java key word `continue`.

The keyword `break` will break out of the for loop altogether.

The keyword `continue` will skip the rest of that iteration of the for loop and start the next iteration of it.

For example:

```
//loops 3 times
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if(i == 1) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println("Iteration #" + i);
}
```

Will print:

```
Iteration #0
Iteration #2
```

This answers the spirit of your question.

**However**, as others have pointed out, `continue` is not actually what you want for your particular example.  What you really want to use is just `j--`.  But for future reference, you now know how to break out of an "if" statement and go back to the top of a for loop.